# rust match: the fallback arm is unreachable matching strings, why?

Tags: rust

code
io::stdin()
.read_line(&mut symbol)
.expect("Failed to read line");

```
    println!("You entered {symbol}");

    let symbol_x: String = format!("{}", ValidMove::X);
    let symbol_o: String = format!("{}", ValidMove::O);

    match &symbol {
        symbol_x => ok = true,
        symbol_o => ok = true,
        _ => ok = false,
    }
```

The compiler warns that

- the 3rd arm is unreachable
- symbol_x is unused
- symbol_y is unused

why!?!?

Comment: You can't match against variables like this, you have to match against a [pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-00-patterns.html), i.e. a literal, destructured tuple, etc. What you're doing here is matching against a _new_ variable called `sumbol_x` that will store the content of `symbol`. That's an _irrefutable_ pattern and that's why it tells you the other ones are unreachable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match against variables, therefore your match statement is equivalent to:

```rust
match &symbol {
    zzz => ok = true,
    yyy => ok = true,
    _ => ok = false,
}
```

Comment: "You cannot match against variables" ... ah, this is new for me... thanks.
I'll use an if a this lap

Comment: See the link from @Jmb in the comment on your question.  That also provides a *match guard* suggestion which is what you probably want to do.